# android linear programming lp_solve library

Tags: android, linear-programming, lpsolve

Can someone help me how to use `lpsolve55j.jar` on Android device. I tried importing it like every other library (putting it in libs folder and adding it in JavaBuildPath -> Libraries) but I got this error:

```
03-07 15:28:52.910: W/dalvikvm(3421): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Llpsolve/LpSolve;
03-07 15:28:52.910: D/AndroidRuntime(3421): Shutting down VM
03-07 15:28:52.910: W/dalvikvm(3421): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9e495930)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lpsolve55j from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.app.cutstockan-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.app.cutstockan-2]: findLibrary returned null
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at lpsolve.LpSolve.<clinit>(LpSolve.java:275)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at com.app.cutstockan.Calculate.generateEquations(Calculate.java:123)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at com.app.cutstockan.Calculate.<init>(Calculate.java:52)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at com.app.cutstockan.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:37)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5202)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-07 15:28:52.910: E/AndroidRuntime(3421):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 15:28:54.650: I/Process(3421): Sending signal. PID: 3421 SIG: 9
```

**EDIT**

OK, so what I need this for is for solving a system of inequalities. Can someone help me to find alternative for this library that can solve this?

Comment: this jar contains native library ... so it will not work on Android if you do not compile native library for Android ...

Comment: @Selvin I found the source for the library, any suggestions how can I compile the library for Android?

Comment: A little offtopic maybe, but you might one to re-think solving LP on Android devices (use a server instead?).

Comment: Granted, I have not tried it myself, but maybe you should be able to build and use the Simplex solver from [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html) in your Android application?

Comment: @adrianp I can't use server because I need to make everything to work without internet connection (locally). It's not so heavy mathematics, if that is what you thought

Comment: @AndersGustafsson As I could see, this library solves only `A*X=B`. I need to solve system of inequalities

Comment: @nikmin But you *do have* an objective function? You can formulate the [LinearConstraint](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/linear/LinearConstraint.html)s of the LP problem as inequalities by specifying the lhs-rhs `Relationship`. Hmmm, I notice now that the [SimplexSolver](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/linear/SimplexSolver.html) is deprecated in Commons Math 3.1, but I do not know the reason why?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I doesn't matter if it's deprecated. Can you please write an usage example as answer? This is used for minimization, right? Thanks

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I figured out how to make the constraints and objective function but how to use `solver.optimize(OptimizationData)`

Comment: @nikmin Please see my answer for further guidance. I hope the referenced examples should give you sufficient help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//) is a pure Java library that contains for example the Simplex algorithm for solving linear programs. Binaries of this library should probably be possible to use as-is in an Android application, alternatively it should be straightforward to build the library specifically for Android.

The associated [unit test cases](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/linear/SimplexSolverTest.java?view=markup) sufficiently illustrates the usage of the *Apache Commons Math* [SimplexSolver](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/linear/SimplexSolver.html) for solving different kinds of smaller LP problems.

Comment: I solved it. But there is one problem. Is there a way the call to `solver.optimize` to return results with integers, not doubles? I want to get the best integers result

Comment: The LP optimizer in *Apache Commons Math* is only capable of handling floating-point variables, integer variables (Mixed Integer Linear Programming) are not supported. I looked around, and right out-of-the-box I cannot find any usable pure Java MILP libraries, unfortunately. There is an ambitious project porting GLPK (which supports integer variables) to *Javascript*, [glpk.js](https://github.com/hgourvest/glpk.js), could this be of use?

Comment: I think this is of no use :( If you find something else I will be very grateful. Thanks for helping