# Searching for proper optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I'm developing a mobile application with an algorithm. It's about food.

So I have a database that contains some meals. A meal contains several foods. A food is an item like an Apple, and it contains the nutrient values of the apple.
A Meal for example could be an apple pie, which contains apples, sugar, etc...

Each Food in a meal has a minimum and maximum amount, to make them more flexible. So when im making pasta with sauce, you can put in 150-250g of pasta and 50-75ml of sauce.

**GOAL:** The Algorithm is supposed to take in some values for total daily intake of carbohydrates, protein and fats. Then it should do some kind of algorithm to figure out a good combination of meals to best match the expectations of daily carbohydrates, proteins and fats.

While finding a solution, the algorithm can swap out meals, change the scaling of the foods inside the meals, and with n meals per day, and n foods per meal, that's quite a lot of variables.

I've tried a genetic algorithm approach, but I couldn't find a way to properly pair 2 solutions to make a child, and I couldn't figure out a good way for mutation.

Any help is appreciated, I don't want any code, just some inspiration at what i should look at, I'm not afraid of reading something (if it's not a book^^).

Or if anyone has an approach on how to handle this problem, that would be very nice aswell!

Comment: Mathematical programming would handle this pretty well, but maybe it's overkill.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using [Mixed Integer Programming (MIP/MILP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

A handy tutorial for this is [here](http://www.ie.boun.edu.tr/~taskin/pdf/IP_tutorial.pdf).

The idea will be to introduce a binary variable for each meal indicating whether or not that meal is used. For each food item in the meal, there will be a variable indicating what portion of that food item is used.

The portions are constrained by user specified values, as are the health values.

Thus, for two meals `m1` and `m2` such that `m1` has a portion `f1` of food 1 and `f2` of food 2 and `m2` has `f3` of food 3 and `f4` of food 4, if we take `m1` and `m2` to be the aforementioned binary variables, then we have constraints like the following:

```
daily_protein_min<=m1*(f1*protein_f1+f2*protein_f2)+m2*(f3*protein_f3+f4*protein_f4)<=daily_protein_max
f1_min<=f1<=f1_max
f2_min<=f2<=f2_max
f3_min<=f3<=f3_max
f4_min<=f4<=f4_max
```

We can also constraint the number of meals per day:

```
m1+m2=1
```

Since multiplying a variable by a variable produces a potentially non-convex, non-linear result, we refer to the [MIP tutorial](http://www.ie.boun.edu.tr/~taskin/pdf/IP_tutorial.pdf) for a way to transform such constrains into a usable form.

Finally, we use [disciplined convex programming](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html) to build a model using [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) to pass to a solver. [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) is a free MIP solver. Commercial solvers like Gurobi are generally faster, allow larger problems, are more stable, and quite expensive, though possibly free for students.

Having done all this, putting the problem into code isn't too terrible. Since I wasn't sure what values to use or what sort of food database was reasonable, I've used essentially random inputs (garbage in, garbage out!).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cvxpy as cp
import csv
from io import StringIO
import random

#CSV file for food data
#Drawn from: https://think.cs.vt.edu/corgis/csv/food/food.html
food_data = """1st Household Weight,1st Household Weight Description,2nd Household Weight,2nd Household Weight Description,Alpha Carotene,Ash,Beta Carotene,Beta Cryptoxanthin,Calcium,Carbohydrate,Category,Cholesterol,Choline,Copper,Description,Fiber,Iron,Kilocalories,Lutein and Zeaxanthin,Lycopene,Magnesium,Manganese,Monosaturated Fat,Niacin,Nutrient Data Bank Number,Pantothenic Acid,Phosphorus,Polysaturated Fat,Potassium,Protein,Refuse Percentage,Retinol,Riboflavin,Saturated Fat,Selenium,Sodium,Sugar Total,Thiamin,Total Lipid,Vitamin A - IU,Vitamin A - RAE,Vitamin B12,Vitamin B6,Vitamin C,Vitamin E,Vitamin K,Water,Zinc
28.35,1 oz,454,1 lb,0,0.75,0,0,13,0.0,LAMB,68,0,0.12,"LAMB,AUS,IMP,FRSH,RIB,LN&FAT,1/8""FAT,RAW",0.0,1.34,289,0,0,18,0.009,9.765,5.103,17314,0.501,156,0.985,254,16.46,26,0,0.232,11.925,6.9,68,0.0,0.145,24.2,0,0,1.62,0.347,0.0,0.0,0.0,59.01,2.51
0.0,,0,,0,0.9,27,0,141,7.0,SOUR CREAM,35,19,0.01,"SOUR CREAM,REDUCED FAT",0.0,0.06,181,0,0,11,0.0,4.1,0.07,1178,0.0,85,0.5,211,7.0,0,117,0.24,8.7,4.1,70,0.300000012,0.04,14.1,436,119,0.3,0.02,0.9,0.4,0.7,71.0,0.27
78.0,"1 bar, 2.8 oz",0,,0,0.0,0,0,192,46.15,CANDIES,13,0,0.0,"CANDIES,HERSHEY'S POT OF GOLD ALMOND BAR",3.799999952,1.85,577,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19130,0.0,0,0.0,0,12.82,0,0,0.0,16.667,0.0,64,38.45999908,0.0,38.46,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
425.0,"1 package,  yields",228,1 serving,0,1.4,0,0,0,9.5,OLD EL PASO CHILI W/BNS,16,0,0.0,"OLD EL PASO CHILI W/BNS,CND ENTREE",4.300000191,1.18,109,0,0,0,0.0,1.87,0.0,22514,0.0,0,0.985,0,7.7,0,0,0.0,0.904,0.0,258,0.0,0.0,4.5,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,76.9,0.0
28.0,1 slice,0,,0,3.6,0,0,0,1.31,TURKEY,48,0,0.0,"TURKEY,BREAST,SMOKED,LEMON PEPPER FLAVOR,97% FAT-FREE",0.0,0.0,95,0,0,0,0.0,0.25,0.0,7943,0.0,0,0.19,0,20.9,0,0,0.0,0.22,0.0,1160,0.0,0.0,0.69,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.5,0.0
140.0,"1 cup, diced",113,"1 cup, shredded",0,5.85,63,0,772,2.1,CHEESE,85,36,0.027,"CHEESE,PAST PROCESS,SWISS,W/DI NA PO4",0.0,0.61,334,0,0,29,0.014,7.046,0.038,1044,0.26,762,0.622,216,24.73,0,192,0.276,16.045,15.9,1370,1.230000019,0.014,25.01,746,198,1.23,0.036,0.0,0.34,2.2,42.31,3.61
263.0,"1 piece, cooked, excluding refuse (yield from 1 lb raw meat with refuse)",85,3 oz,0,1.22,0,0,20,0.0,LAMB,91,0,0.108,"LAMB,DOM,SHLDR,WHL (ARM&BLD),LN&FAT,1/8""FAT,CHOIC,CKD,RSTD",0.0,1.97,269,0,0,23,0.022,7.79,6.04,17245,0.7,185,1.56,251,22.7,24,0,0.24,7.98,26.4,66,0.0,0.09,19.08,0,0,2.65,0.13,0.0,0.0,0.0,56.98,5.44
17.0,1 piece,0,,0,0.7,10,0,49,76.44,CANDIES,14,10,0.329,"CANDIES,FUDGE,CHOC,PREPARED-FROM-RECIPE",1.700000048,1.77,411,4,0,36,0.422,2.943,0.176,19100,0.14,71,0.373,134,2.39,0,43,0.085,6.448,2.5,45,73.12000275,0.026,10.41,159,44,0.09,0.012,0.0,0.18,1.4,9.81,1.11
124.0,"1 serving, 1/2 cup",0,,0,1.98,0,0,32,9.68,CAMPBELL SOUP,4,0,0.0,"CAMPBELL SOUP,CAMPBELL'S RED & WHITE,BROCCOLI CHS SOUP,COND",0.0,0.0,81,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,6014,0.0,0,0.0,0,1.61,0,0,0.0,1.613,0.0,661,1.610000014,0.0,3.63,806,0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,83.1,0.0
142.0,"1 item, 5 oz",0,,0,3.23,0,0,109,22.26,MCDONALD'S,167,0,0.073,"MCDONALD'S,BACON EGG & CHS BISCUIT",0.899999976,2.13,304,0,0,12,0.137,5.546,1.959,21360,0.642,335,2.625,121,13.45,0,0,0.416,8.262,0.0,863,2.180000067,0.262,18.77,399,0,0.0,0.093,2.1,0.0,0.0,42.29,0.9"""

#Convert to dictionary
food_data = [dict(x) for x in csv.DictReader(StringIO(food_data))]
food_data = [x for x in food_data if float(x['1st Household Weight'])!=0]

#Values to track
quantities = ['Protein', 'Carbohydrate', 'Total Lipid', 'Kilocalories']

#Create random meals
meals = []
for mealnum in range(10):
  meal = {"name": "Meal #{0}".format(mealnum), "foods":[]}
  for x in range(random.randint(2,4)): #Choose a random number of foods to be in meal
    food = random.choice(food_data)
    food['min'] = 10                   #Use large bounds to ensure we have a feasible solution
    food['max'] = 1000
    weight               = float(food['1st Household Weight']) #Number of units in a standard serving
    for q in quantities:
      #Convert quantities to per-unit measures
      food[q] = float(food[q])/weight 
    meal['foods'].append(food)
  meals.append(meal)

#Create an optimization problem from the meals
total_daily_carbs_min   = 225
total_daily_carbs_max   = 325
total_daily_protein_min = 46
total_daily_protein_max = 56
total_daily_lipids_min  = 44
total_daily_lipids_max  = 78

#Construct variables, totals, and some constraints
constraints = []
for meal in meals:
  #Create a binary variable indicating whether we are using the variable
  meal['use_meal']     = cp.Variable(boolean=True) 
  for q in quantities:
    meal[q] = 0
  for food in meal['foods']:
    food['portion'] = cp.Variable(pos=True)
    #Ensure that we only use an appropriate amount of this food
    constraints.append( food['min']     <= food['portion'] )
    constraints.append( food['portion'] <= food['max']     )
    #Calculate this meal's contributions to the totals.
    #Each items contribution is the portion times the per-unit quantity times a
    #boolean (0, 1) variable indicating whether or not we use the meal
    for q in quantities:
      meal[q] += food['portion']*food[q]

#Dictionary with no sums of meals, yet
totals = {q:0 for q in quantities}

#See: "http://www.ie.boun.edu.tr/~taskin/pdf/IP_tutorial.pdf", "Nonlinear Product Terms"
#Since multiplying to variables produces a non-convex, nonlinear function, we
#have to use some trickery
#Let w have the value of `meal['use_meal']*meal['Protein']`
#Let x=meal['use_meal'] and y=meal['Protein']
#Let u be an upper bound on the value of meal['Protein']
#We will make constraints such that
#   w <= u*y                  
#   w >=0                     if we don't use the meal, `w` is zero
#   w <= y                    if we do use the meal, `w` must not be larger than the meal's value
#   w >= u*(x-1)+y            if we use the meal, then `w>=y` and `w<=y`, so `w==y`; otherwise, `w>=-u+y`

u = 9999 #An upper bound on the value of any meal quantity
for meal in meals:
  for q in quantities:
    w = cp.Variable()
    constraints.append( w<=u*meal['use_meal']             )
    constraints.append( w>=0                              )
    constraints.append( w<=meal[q]                        )
    constraints.append( w>=u*(meal['use_meal']-1)+meal[q] )
    totals[q] += w

#Construct constraints. The totals must be within the ranges given
constraints.append( total_daily_protein_min <= totals['Protein']      )
constraints.append( total_daily_carbs_min   <= totals['Carbohydrate'] )
constraints.append( total_daily_lipids_min  <= totals['Total Lipid']  )
constraints.append( totals['Protein']       <= total_daily_protein_max)
constraints.append( totals['Carbohydrate']  <= total_daily_carbs_max  )
constraints.append( totals['Total Lipid']   <= total_daily_lipids_max )



#Ensure that we're doing three meals because this is the number of meals people
#in some countries eat.
constraints.append( sum([meal['use_meal'] for meal in meals])==3 )

#With an objective value of 1 we are asking the solver to identify any feasible
#solution. We don't care which one.
objective = cp.Minimize(1)

#We could also use:
#objective = cp.Minimize(totals['Kilocalories'])
#to meet nutritional needs while minimizing calories intake

problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

val = problem.solve(solver=cp.GLPK_MI, verbose=True)

if val==1:
  for q in quantities:
    print("{0} = {1}".format(q, totals[q].value))
  for m in meals:
    if m['use_meal'].value!=1:
      continue
    print(m['name'])
    for f in m['foods']:
      print("\t{0} units of {1} (min={2}, max={3})".format(f['portion'].value, f['Description'], f['min'], f['max']))
```

The result looks like this:

```
Protein = 46.0
Carbohydrate = 224.99999999999997
Total Lipid = 69.68255808922696
Kilocalories = 1719.4249142101326
Meal #1
  10.0 units of TURKEY,BREAST,SMOKED,LEMON PEPPER FLAVOR,97% FAT-FREE (min=10, max=1000)
  10.0 units of MCDONALD'S,BACON EGG & CHS BISCUIT (min=10, max=1000)
  1000.0 units of CANDIES,FUDGE,CHOC,PREPARED-FROM-RECIPE (min=10, max=1000)
  1000.0 units of OLD EL PASO CHILI W/BNS,CND ENTREE (min=10, max=1000)
Meal #2
  999.9999999960221 units of CAMPBELL SOUP,CAMPBELL'S RED & WHITE,BROCCOLI CHS SOUP,COND (min=10, max=1000)
  10.0 units of LAMB,AUS,IMP,FRSH,RIB,LN&FAT,1/8"FAT,RAW (min=10, max=1000)
  10.0 units of TURKEY,BREAST,SMOKED,LEMON PEPPER FLAVOR,97% FAT-FREE (min=10, max=1000)
  10.0 units of MCDONALD'S,BACON EGG & CHS BISCUIT (min=10, max=1000)
Meal #5
  1000.0 units of OLD EL PASO CHILI W/BNS,CND ENTREE (min=10, max=1000)
  221.06457214122466 units of CHEESE,PAST PROCESS,SWISS,W/DI NA PO4 (min=10, max=1000)
  10.0 units of LAMB,DOM,SHLDR,WHL (ARM&BLD),LN&FAT,1/8"FAT,CHOIC,CKD,RSTD (min=10, max=1000)
```

For reasons that are unclear to me, GLPK fails pretty often, though it does find a solution about 1 out of 20 times. This is disappointing since failing to find a solution looks the same as if it had proven there is *no* solution.

At the moment, I guess I'd recommend running it a larger number of times to before ruling out the possibility of a solution.

Note that adding more foods and meals should make it easier for the solver to find a solution and reduce the frequency of the problem above.

---

Another way to approach this problem would be to enumerate subsets of meals, such as all subsets of three meals a day. Determining whether a given subset of meals satisfies portion and nutrient constraints is then a linear programming which can be solved quickly and easily. The downside to this is that there may be a large number of meal combinations to enumerate. MIP solvers may have techniques to reduce the number of combinations that need to be searched.

Comment: First of all thanks for the time you took to help me and the detailed description!

Unfortunately I can only use Dart (if you don't know it it's kinda like JavaScript) in my programming, and there probably is no library to implement the MIP. So I probably have to write the algorithm all by myself with rather basic operations...

I don't understand yet how the algorithm gets a good solutions. I understand how you check constraints of the food and the daily nutrients, but I don't understand yet how it produces any solutions and how to find an optimal solution.

Comment: @01leo: It would have been good to mention this constraint in your question before I spent the time to put this answer together. You should edit your question to be more clear about what you can and cannot do.

Comment: @01leo: What about [this](https://hgourvest.github.io/glpk.js/) and [this](https://github.com/jvail/glpk.js). Generating combinations and using LPs should be do-able within JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately Dart is just like JavaScript, but not compatible with it. And I don't know if I can port the whole library... I was wondering if one could understand how the algorithm works and then I can write it in Dart... You don't have to explain it by yourself if you don't want, a link would be fine aswell^^

Comment: @01leo: You could solve the linear programs using the [tableau method](https://www.utdallas.edu/~scniu/OPRE-6201/documents/LP06-Simplex-Tableau.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a variation of the theme of the [Diet Problem](https://neos-guide.org/content/diet-problem), and Mathematical Programming is an effective approach, as [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752843/richard) clearly pointed out. However this may not be feasible in your case, since there are not many libraries for mathematical programming on mobile devices (may some can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273887/android-linear-programming-lp-solve-library)), but I am not aware of any DART libraries for linear programming.

As an alternative, a [metaheuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) approach might work well, and you have plenty of alternatives, including [Genetic Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

Independently of the algorithm you are going to adopt, one choice you need to make is how to encode solutions. The most natural choice would be to use non-negative continuous (i.e., real) decision variables: let's call them x<sub>fm</sub>, representing the amount of food f at meal m (it does not matter whether m is the 3rd meal of the 5th day of the 2nd week: just number them progressively). Two subscripts, so they form a matrix of values of F rows times M columns. One natural way to encode them would be to unroll that matrix into a vector x<sub>i</sub>, i.e., write each row of the matrix one after the other in an array, so that each subscript i identifies a specific pair (f,m).

Next you need to clearly define what the objective function is and have a procedure for calculating it from your encoded solutions.

Next you need a procedure for generating new solutions to be evaluated (look at point 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184070/job-scheduling-to-minimise-loss/54445784#54445784) for some ideas).

If you wish to stick with genetic algorithms, here are [some ideas for mutation and crossover](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3428/mutation-and-crossover-in-a-genetic-algorithm-with-real-numbers), just make sure to preserve non-negativity.